# Access wcf from netcoreapp2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a asp dotnet core 2.0 project that needs to talk to a downstream WCF service

The proj file is targeting `netcoreapp2.0`

I have added nuget packages for `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` and have almost everything I need apart from something in the `System.ServiceModel.Configuration` namespace which doesnt appear to be available on Nuget

In the past, I have successfully talked to the WCF service in a netcore1.1 project (by making it target net461)

However, this doesnt appear to be an option if you want to take advantage of netCore2.0 functionality. If you target net461 then you cant access netcore2.0 features

Should this be possible?

Am I doing something wrong?

Can you target net461 and also use netcore2.0 features?

or is there a way I can target netcoreapp2.0 and still access `System.ServiceModel.Configuration`?

Or do I need to target netcoreapp2.0 and do something else that allows me to access `System.ServiceModel.Configuration`?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use at least VS 2017 version 15.5, you can add the WCF service as a connected service. The wizard will add the required packages and generate the client code. (in previous VS 2017 versions, you'd need a preview extension).

You can access this wizard from the "Add Connected Service" context menu item:

[image: Add connected service]

[image: Connected services]

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of that. However, there is still a specific channel factory that I need access to which is the namespace mentioned above. thanks though

Comment: You can look for issues about this at https://github.com/dotnet/wcf. The wcf client libs on .net core are only a subset of those supported on full .net framework

Comment: yeah, seemingly so. It's irritating as I was able to access the channelfactory I need when targeting net461. Which I guess makes sense. as that's full .net. Basically, I want to use net core 2.0 features but still be able to reference this particular duplex channel factory - thanks again

Comment: so have tried to target net471. That gives me access to netcore2.0 features and also the wcf stuff I need. However, I get the following compilation error "Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0 is not compatible with net471" . any ideas on that? Does targetting net471 seem like a reasonable plan? Oh and have the latest nuget so its not that

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.All only works on .NET Core, not on .NET Framework. If you want to use .NET Framework for ASP.NET Core Apps, you need to reference the packages you need individually.

Comment: (don't confuse "ASP.NET Core" with ".NET Core", if you switch to net471, you are no longer using .NET Core)

Comment: essentially , I just want to use the new signalr stuff (which I think requires netcore2.0). And additionally be able to call this wcf service. not bothered about other 2.0 stuff. only actually need signalr

Comment: afaik the new SignalR targets netstandard2.0 so you can use it from both .net framework > 2.0 and .net core > 2.0

Comment: so if I traget net471 (to get the wcf stuff to work), is there something other than  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0 that I can reference to get an asp proj running?

Comment: and of course be able to use new signalr - thanks again

Comment: sure, `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and others, just see the dependencies of the .all meta package at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/